# Поиск в таблице и выдача её значений

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, таблицы

Я беру значение ans из таблицы. Как его вывести на сайт [как здесь](http://google.com/robots.txt)?
Код:

```
if (isset($_GET['que'])) {
  $query = "SELECT ans FROM `capbase` WHERE QUE=".$_GET['que'];
  $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query) or die(mysqli_error());
  if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
      $myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
        {
            echo "yes";
        }
      }else{
    echo 'none';
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_GET['que'])) {
  $query = "SELECT ans FROM `capbase` WHERE QUE=".$_GET['que'];
  $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query) or die(mysqli_error());
  if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($sql)) {
    echo "<li>$row[0]</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
  }else{
    echo 'none';
  }
mysqli_free_result($sql);
}
```